# jQuery UI: Animate from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery animate from right to left. My JS code looks like this:

```
$('.tabs').each(function(index){
    $(this).click(function(event){
        $('.tabs').css('left', '1410px').removeClass('open');
        $('.blocks').css('width', '0px');
        $('.blocks').css('left', '1385px');
        $(this).animate({left: '1397px'}, 200).addClass('open');
        $('.blocks').eq(index).animate({left: '520px'}, 2500);          
        });
    });
```

The rest of the code you can see in my fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DM346/5/

As you see it animates correctly (from right to left) but the whole textblock is transparent (I know its because I set the width to 0, but I have to do it because in other way it will pop up on the buttons).

I want to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/19/
but from right to left as in my example. Can somebody help? Basically the problem is the "invisibility" of the textblock.

Comment: your code is so hard to debug. Could you please at least reduce -scale- the numbers so it fits in the jsfiddle screens?

Comment: I updated my fiddle code. Take a look now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use z-index to place the containers properly, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DM346/6/)

add:

```
#tabs-cont {
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:20;
}

.blocks {
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Wrap the tabs in a div

```
<div id="tabs-cont">
    <div class="tabs" id="tab1">HOME</div>
    <div class="tabs" id="tab2">VIDEO</div>
    <div class="tabs" id="tab3">TEXT</div>
    <div class="tabs" id="tab4">CONTACT US</div>
    <div class="tabs" id="tab5">HELP</div>
</div>
```

and change js to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabs').each(function (index) {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            $('.tabs').css('left', '895px').removeClass('open');
            $('.blocks').css('left', '875px');
            $('.blocks').css('width', '865px');
            $(this).animate({
                left: '875px'
            }, 200).addClass('open');
            $('.blocks').eq(index).animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, 2500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i tested it already with z-index... it works but it's not 100% what I want because you can see it behind the buttons :/ but if there is no other option I will leave it there.

Comment: Here i a print screen how it actually looks:
http://gyazo.com/ed878b6a3a460edb69b8c06336302aa8.png
You see? The z-index thing dont work as good as I wanted :/

Comment: Well, this is a hacky approach. What you really need to be doing is setting all the `div`'s with the content to `display:none` and then adding a class to toggle visibility, while all the other ones are hidden from view

Comment: You can set a width to the `body` and then `overflow:hidden` to hide the other slides, but this isn't the *best approach* though it will work updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DM346/8/)

Comment: To be honest this still does not look good... You can see the blocks after the button and you can clearly see the text thats in those blocks. I think it's not possible to hack it in such a simple way :/

Comment: do you know maybe how can i get into the animate() time? Because there would be a plan to increase the block "width" from lets say 150px (so it is invisible at the beginning, behind the buttons) to 875px while the time form animate() passes by... Any Idea how to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix this issue! I used the step() function from jQuery animate() :)
var time = 2500;

```
    var blockWidth = 0;
    $('.blocks').eq(index).css('width', '0px');
    $('.blocks').eq(index).animate(
    {
    left: '520px'
    },
    {
        duration: time,
        step: function( test ){
            if(blockWidth < 865)
            {
                console.log( "blockWidth: ", blockWidth);
                blockWidth +=6;
            }                   
            $('.blocks').eq(index).css('width', blockWidth);
        }
    }
    );
```

Now it works perfectly! :)